# AWS SNS for mobile push notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

does SNS support emoji, images, deep linking for mobile push notifications. if yes can you please share a sample scheme for consuming SNS APIs for these features.A

Answer (score 2):

- ***deep links***

I've read the SNS documentation and it appears that currently Amazon SNS doesn't support ***"deep links"*** feature.

I would like to refer you to another AWS service called [Amazon Pinpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/deep-linking-track-mobile-engagement-users/) which I know supports deep linking.

- ***images***

Amazon SNS indeed supports sending Push Notification with images, however there are two major key things to consider :

**1.** The image size must not exceed 256KB which is the max payload size of the Publish API call.

**2.** It's the responsibility of the mobile application to process the payload and display the desired image appropriately. e.g the following 'data' message payload could be processed by the app by extracting the key ImageUrl (or any other key) and display the image accordingly.

```
{
  "GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"body\": \"SNS body\",  \"title\": \"SNS\", \"ImageUrl\": \"https://syumaK-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/Mahrez.png\" } }"
}
```

- ***emoji***

Amazon SNS indeed supports emoji when sending Push Notification. You can do the following :

**( i )** Copy & paste the [emoji's](https://getemoji.com/) directly into your payload as illustrated below :

```
 {
   "GCM":"{ \"notification\": { \"text\": \"Riyad Mahrez, ⚽️ against former club to put Manchester City back in the EPL title \" } }"
 }
```

[Click here to view sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AN3F.png)

**( ii )** Send the [emoji unicode characters](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) in the payload as illustrated below :

```
{
   "GCM":"{ \"notification\": { \"text\": \"This is a test notification \u270C\" } }"
}
```

[Click here to view sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHgQZ.png)

Hope this helps!